# Debugging async controller with async service inside

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, task

It's MVC project. I've started making some heavy calls to remote api async, but I am having problems debugging this code, because it is not entering breakpoint after await. I am still learning the async/await. GetSearchResults method in used in ajax requests on frontend. Application is hosted in IIS.

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSearchResults(SearchRequest searchModel)
{           
    var result = await _apiSearchService.SearchAsync(searchModel);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And here is my method inside service:

```
public async Task<Search> SearchAsync(SearchRequest searchRequest)
{
    var requestUrl = "api/search";
    var request = new NewtonsoftRestRequest(requestUrl, Method.GET);

    /*
        ...assigning params
    */

    var response = await _apiClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
    var searchResults = _apiClient.ResolveResponse<Search>(response);
    return searchResults;
}
```

When I hit line

```
await _apiSearchService.SearchAsync(searchModel);
```

I enter `SearchAsync` method and after line with `ExecuteTaskAsync` I am leaving debugging at all and get my page hit.

```
var response = await _apiClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
```

Could someone tell me how can debugging be achieved here? Also, could someone do a quick code review, if I am using async/await well? Also maybe I should use Task.Run() ? Going deeper is really getting more and more confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: Could be an exception in ExecuteTaskAsync(). Adding a try/catch at some level will give you a lot more information.

Comment: Just same as multithread debugging  please refer https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/how-to-debug-multithread-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was unhandled exception in my method. Thanks @bommelding